# Best way to move files from Dev to Live site (django)

Tags: svn, deployment

I've got a svn checkout locally which I make changes to, once I commit them I go in and  update my dev copy on the server.

My question is, what's the best way to get my files to my production site.  I'm not much with linux commands, but I was thinking I could make a script that moves all files except .pyc and .svn files over to my production site?  I don't really know what the best way is and I would like to hear from some experts on how to do it the right way.

Comment: This is not a python question.  Try the tags "svn, deployment, scripting"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I generally run directly from an svn checkout. Log in to the production server, update to the revision or tag that's been deemed worthy, restart the server and you're good to go.

This has the advantage that it forces you to make sure that *everything* is kept under version control because the production site comes straight out of the repository. You could obviously automate the deployment using something like [Fabric](http://www.nongnu.org/fab/) if you wanted to.

Comment: Greatly agree. However I would recommend running from an "export" instead of a checkout, so that you don't have all those hidden .svn folders and their contents hanging around on your web server.

Comment: I disagree. I find the fact that it's a live checkout is useful for audit purposes. You want to know what version is on the server: svn log. You want to know if anyone has changed anything: svn status or svn diff. You might be concerned about confidentiality issues of having the .svn directories lying around, but if someone can read them they can read all your code anyway. So I wouldn't delete them just for the sake of "neatness".

Answer (score 3):

Can't you keep a svn repo (maybe a R/O one) on your server and just have it `svn up` when needed? This way svn:ignore can take care of the business of ignoring certain files, &c.

If that's too cumbersome I would work by packaging up a "release" (set of files tested and working together) when ready (also tagging it for easy rollback in svn) -- say into a .tar.bz2 or .zip archive -- and send that to the server where it gets expanded. This way you have a good track of exactly what you released when and can deal with QA bug reports more easily; it will also be a lifesaver if you ever need to get into the branching business.

More generally, [release engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Release_engineering) is an important and often-underrated discipline, and it's well worth reading up on it, even if right now you don't yet need to do anything complicated or highly structured in that field.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to run your own repo server and are willing to spend some time learning mercurial or git, you can quickly setup a public or private repository at bitbucket or github.

The flow is: do your commits locally, push to online repo, login to your server, switch to the project and pull the changes. One rule of thumb is to never edit project code on the server, always commit locally and push, then pull to the server. local_settings.py is the only file that I edit directly on the server.

I use a pip requirements file for external dependencies, and its as easy as typing 'pip install --requirement external_apps.txt' to keep dependencies in sync. It also helps to use virtualenv to manage multiple projects (at the very least locally) and a fabric deployment script to simplify the deployment process.

Oh, and all VCS has a .ignore file where you can prevent files like local_settings.py and *.pyc files from appearing in your repo.